# Dashed line shader in A-Frame

Tags: shader, line, aframe

So, I've got a basic line added in A-Frame and I want it to be dotted/dashed. I know there is a ThreeJS material called [LineDashedMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/LineDashedMaterial) which does exactly [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lines_dashed), but how do I use it in A-Frame?

Any idea what I have to add to this code to do that? I know I have to create a custom shader that uses the ThreeJS material, but how?

LINK: https://codepen.io/marcel_pi/pen/wvMrPXj

Thank you.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.0.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene id="scene" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
      
        <a-camera id="camera" name="mainCamera" camera="fov: 45;" position="0 0 0" look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 0 0; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 1500; initialPosition: 20 20 20;" camera-distance position-listener>
        </a-camera>

        <a-entity line="start: 0 -10 -10; end: 0 10 10; color: #000;"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame is based on three.js. The key is to find out how you add three.js objects to your A-Frame scene.

Two steps:

1. Create the dashed line using three.js functions
2. Add the line to your A-Frame scene

```js
var material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
  color: "white",
  dashSize: 0.5,
  gapSize: 0.5
});

var geometry= new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
  new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, -10),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 10)
);

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
line.computeLineDistances();
document.querySelector("a-scene").object3D.add(line);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.0.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>

<a-scene id="scene" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" background="color:black">
  <a-camera id="camera" name="mainCamera" camera="fov: 45;" position="0 0 0" look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 0 0; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 1500; initialPosition: 20 20 20;" camera-distance position-listener>
  </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

More about working with three.js in A-Frame: https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/developing-with-threejs.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the threejs way of drawing a line.

My question was more like: Is there a way I can use the LineDashedMaterial by registering it as a shader in A-Frame and then applying it to an <a-entity line=".."> rather than doing everything manually the threejs way in javascript?

I'd really appreciate if anyone shared how you can declare that shader, or if it's even possible.

Then a-frame docs do not provide a lot of info.

Comment: What you can do is create a custom component like "dashed-line" based on the "line" component (see the source on github) and incorporate the code ffmaer provided to build it the way you want. Then you can use it in any entity like a regular line and it will use your custom code :)

Comment: I did create a component based on the a-frame 'line' component and added it to a line entity and.. nothing happens.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong or I need to add?

https://codepen.io/marcel_pi/pen/wvMrPXj